# Proof for Financial Mathematics

Tags: finance

Assuming that the annual interest rate $r$ is constant, show that the present value of an infinite stream of annual payments of the form $C,Cg,Cg^2,\dots$ growing at a constant rate g, is given by the formula
$$\frac{C}{1+r-g}$$
I don't understand at all how to get this result. I see that
$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$$
So this would be
$$C+Cg+Cg^2+\cdots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}Cg^k = \frac{C}{1-g}$$
How am I supposed to have the result above? I don't see how at all.

Comment: Your last series expression is not the present value. It does not include discounting. What would be the present value of an infinite stream of constant annual payments $C, C, \dots$w.r.t. a discount rate $r$?

Comment: I don't know... Like what is even meant by the present value? What would that be? Would it be $C+Cr+Cr^2+\cdots$ ?? @Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\left|\frac{g}{1+r}\right|<1$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
PV &= \frac{C}{1+r}+\frac{Cg}{(1+r)^2}+\frac{Cg^2}{(1+r)^3}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{C}{g}\times\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g^k}{(1+r)^k}\\
&=\frac{C}{g}\times \frac{\frac{g}{1+r}}{1-\frac{g}{1+r}}\\
&=\frac{C}{1+r-g}
\end{align}
$$
using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Oh that is so much more clear now. Thank you very much @alexjo

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$C+C(g-r)+C(g-r)^2+.....=\frac {C}{1+r-g}.$$

Note that the rate in this case is rate in minus rate out .